# Convert sql to json without tuple Php/Laravel

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel

I was wondering if there was a library or classes that convert sql to json without duplicates but still with foreign keys.

UPDATE question :

I want to convert a sql query (which will be done in php) and get the input of the query to be able to format it without leaving the tuples that are generated because of the foreign keys

Their is an example of convert that I wanted :

sql request in php :

```
SELECT * FROM `test` join `from` as fr on fr.test_id = test.id
```

Their is a foreign key between from.test_id and test.id that just show from_name

Example of the query output

Their is the result that I wanted in php avec his convertion to json and formatting:

```
result : {'id', 'name', 'first_name', 'email', 'from':[
                        {'id':'1', 'name_from':'coucou toi', 'test_id':'2'}, 
                        {'id':'2', 'name_from':'yes no', 'test_id':'2'}
]}
```

And maybe choose which line to keep as only name, surname, email.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: I think you mean your trying to convert the output from a piece of SQL into JSON, am I right

Comment: In answer, No there is no Magic Function to convert that query result into that JSON. But it is not difficult to do with a little bit of code

Comment: I find this question to be Unclear because of the imprecise [mcve]. I might recommend that you provide a working db fiddle demo link for us with realistic sample data and then tell us your exact desired result from that sample data.  The most ideal way to share your data may be via phpize.online

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) with core functions and some clever SQL writing. There is no need of any framework:

```php
// Please change the connection string
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306', 'test', 'password');

// Renamed all column of the `from` table to `from.xxx`
$stmt = $db->prepare('
  SELECT
    `test`.*,
    `from`.`id` as `from.id`,
    `from`.`name_from` as `from.name_from`,
    `from`.`test_id` as `from.test_id`
  FROM `test`
    join `from` on (`from`.test_id = test.id);
');
$result = $stmt->execute();

// Re-map the `from.xxx` row values into `from` key.
$mapped = array_map(
    fn ($row) => array_merge(
        array_filter($row, fn($key) => strpos($key, 'from.') !== 0, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY),
        ['from' => array_filter($row, fn($key) => strpos($key, 'from.') === 0, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)]
    ),
    $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
);

echo json_encode($mapped, 
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```